# Alias empty command in terminal

Tags: terminal, zsh, xterm

I would like to clear my terminal upon hitting submitting an empty command. In other words, I would like to call `clear` when I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> on empty line. Is that possible?

I understand that is not how the terminal works, but there might be a nice hack such as binding the Enter key and checking terminal or something.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This function should do what you want; all it does it to check if the current prompt input (`$BUFFER`) is empty (`-z`):

```
magic-enter () {
        if [[ -z $BUFFER ]]
        then
                zle clear-screen
        else
                zle accept-line
        fi
}
```

Define it as a widget with

```
zle -N magic-enter
```

and then bind it to `[ENTER]`:

```
bindkey "^M" magic-enter
```

If you use a non-standard key binding for `[Enter]`, adapt the line with `zle accept-line`. You can check with `bindkey  | grep "\^M"`.