# Reset bash prompt at the vertical middle of terminal window on double-enter?

Tags: bash, terminal

Everything is in the title. The idea would be to be able to reset the bash prompt at the vertical middle of a terminal window when hitting twice <kbd>↩</kbd>. A very nice answer was posted [here](https://superuser.com/a/1389923/1111403), but works only for Zsh.

Anybody would have a Bash solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vcent () {
   local n m i
   m="$((LINES/2))"
   n="$((LINES-m))"
   for ((i=0; i<m; i++)); do
      printf '\n'
   done
   printf "\033[${n};0H"
}
```

The function uses the "position the cursor" ANSI escape sequence (seen [here](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html)).

<kbd>Enter</kbd> should be equivalent to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>. To assign the function to <kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, invoke this:

```
bind -x '"\C-m\C-m": vcent'
```

Notes:

- <kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> will not make you lose the line you're currently typing.
- When you hit a single <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute a command, you will experience delay. Bash (strictly: Readline) needs to wait to make sure it's not <kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>. This is governed by `keyseq-timeout` variable in Readline, the default value is `500` (milliseconds).
- Sometimes users hold <kbd>Enter</kbd> to move the prompt to the bottom (and if the original command line is not empty then the first <kbd>Enter</kbd> will execute it). By holding <kbd>Enter</kbd> you can generate a number of keystrokes. In our setup, depending on if the number is odd or even, you will trigger the function (possibly multiple times) or the function *and* an additional (last) <kbd>Enter</kbd> that will execute the current line. The line may or may not be executed, but in either case you will not move the prompt to the bottom. If you ever need to do this, hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>. This combination should act like a normal <kbd>Enter</kbd> but our binding doesn't affect it.
- To make the binding permanent, add the function and `bind …` to your `~/.bashrc`.
- If you paste some text (shell code) into your command line and there is an empty line in it, then Readline may get <kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, so adjacent lines may be concatenated and this is very wrong (possibly dangerous). To avoid this, set `enable-bracketed-paste` to `On` in Readline.