# How do you bind double tap key in Zsh only if the input is empty?

Tags: shell, zsh, key-binding

I am trying to bind double tab to `clear` command only if input in terminal is empty in zsh shell.

What I have achieved up to this point is always delete with double tab but I want to add the condition if possible, adding the following to the .zshrc:

`bindkey -s '\t\t' 'clear^M'`

Maybe, do I need to call a custom function with the key-binding to check if the input is empty?

Any ideas to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, a custom function should do the trick. Have a look at my answer here, which should only need some tweaks: https://superuser.com/a/625663/195224
If you succeeded, don't hesitate and write an answer to your own question yourself (this is good practice on Superuser `:)`

Comment: Thanks @mpy for the answer you give. I asked for something similar in the magic-enter plugin repository, I will give the code in the answers.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior can be achieved with this code:

```
if ! typeset -f magic-double-tab-cmd >/dev/null; then
function magic-double-tab-cmd {
    echo 'clear'
}
fi

function magic-double-tab {
    # Only run magic-double-tab commands when the command line is empty and
    # when on the first line (PS1)
if ! (( $#BUFFER )) && [[ "$CONTEXT" == start ]]; then
    BUFFER=$(magic-double-tab-cmd)
    zle accept-line -w
fi
}
zle -N magic-double-tab
bindkey '\t\t' magic-double-tab
```

Taken from the [magic-enter](https://github.com/zshzoo/magic-enter/issues/1) repository.

This is a similar approach of what magic-enter plugin do but with tab instead.